# How to dodge a DRY issue when calling a function with a constant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, constants

I am still new to Javascript. I need to attach a function to handle events on some of my HTML elements.

I am doing the following:

```
$('#iinp0').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp0');});
$('#iinp1').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp1');});
$('#iinp2').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp2');});
$('#iinp3').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp3');});
$('#iinp4').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp4');});
$('#iinp5').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp5');});
$('#iinp6').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp6');});
$('#iinp7').keyup(function(){keyReleased('iinp7');});
```

I was hoping I could apply the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle with the following:

```
for (i=0;i<=7;i++) {

    var tmp = 'iinp' + i;
    $('#'+tmp).keyup(function(){keyReleased(tmp);});

}
```

but `keyReleased()` is not called with the proper values.

Is there a solution to this issue? I mean is there a simple way to attach my functions having a constant parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply this:

```
$('#iinp0, #iinp1, #iinp2, #iinp3, #iinp4, #iinp5, #iinp6, #iinp7').keyup(function()
{
    keyReleased(this.id);
});
```

---

You could even replace that long selector with an attribute selector:

```
$('[id^=iinp]').keyup(function()
{
    keyReleased(this.id);
});
```

which will select any element who's id starts with `iinp`.

**Note:** This selector is a tad slower than the pure ID selectors - but is much easier to read and maintain (if you could qualify it with a tag selector, it'll be a bit faster).

Answer (score 2):

In your case this would be the best:

```
$('[id^="iinp"]').keyup(function()
{
    keyReleased(this.id);
});
```

But you may like to hear the reason it doesn't work: it's because JavaScript binds the `tmp` var to the bigger scope.

The following code works because we are explicitly binding the current value of `tmp` to the new function being created:

```
for (i=0;i<=7;i++) {

    var tmp = 'iinp' + i;

    $("#"+tmp).keyup((function(xtmp){ return function(){keyReleased(xtmp);} })(tmp));
}
```

Comment: Note that the "bigger scope" is always the `function` in which the `var` is declared. JavaScript is **function-scoped**, instead of **block-scoped** like many other languages. This means that e.g. `for` loops do not start a new scope. The JavaScript interpreter "hoists" the `var` declaration out of the `for` loop to the top of the `function` before running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use numbered ids.

Instead use a class.

```
$('.iinp').keyup(function() {
  var index = $(this).index('.iinp');
  keyReleased('iinp', index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input class="input" id="iinp0" />
<input class="input" id="iinp1" />
<input class="input" id="iinp2" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('.input').keyup(function() {
        keyReleased(this.id.replace('iinp', ''));
    });
    function keyReleased(key) {
        console.log(key)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each one of your inputs have the same class, or are the same element type (like `input`), you can assign them all to the same function using a selector and the `on()` function, and pass the id of the element to the `keyReleased()` function:

Example HTML:

```
<div id="formData">
    <input type="text" id="iinp0" \>
    <input type="text" id="iinp1" \>    
</div>
```

jQuery JavaScript:

```
$("#formData").on("keyup", "input", function() {
    keyReleased($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4SKgU/

Answer (score 0):

The rest of these answers will do what you want, but personally I'd go a step further to reduce the amount of anonymous functions being made (although, some approaches will not do that):

**Use classes for your input**

```
<input class="keyup" id="iinp01" />
```

**Bind using class and non-anonymous event handler**

```
(function ($) { // closure

    $(function () { // on document ready
        $("input.keyup").keyup(keyReleased);
    });

    function keyReleased(e) {
        var id = this.id,
            $input = $(this);

        // Do whatever you want
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Hopefully that will help. If you aren't familiar with closures, learn about them!

If possible, I'd also provide a parent element for context:

```
<div id="keyup-container"><!-- inputs here --></div>

$("#keyup-container input.keyup")
```

It will be more efficient (if you are worried about that).